# Comparing two small audio files (e.g., hand clap) Android

Tags: fft, correlation, audio-processing

Dears,
I am new in signal processing and I am dealing with an Android application that should do some audio files (having the same "small" duration) comparison in real time.
My main focus is about **comparing two small audio** files (about 10 seconds each one) which are related to a **hand clap** for example (or other sounds related to one short event like ball falling).
In other terms, I should save **a reference audio file** (or a significant representation you may suggest) and then compare (in real time) a newly recorded audio file with the one already saved.
For instance, if my audio of reference is a hand clap so I decide that the 2 audios are similar if the second one includes a clap even if there are some noises or the 2 sounds intensity is not the same.

I already checked musicg lib for doing this kind of comparison however, I have to convert my recorded audio files to .wav which may add some slowness in my real time application.
I am wondering if there is another alternative that fits better small audio files (about 10 seconds) having the same duration ?

Thanks in advance for your suggestions and help.

Comment: It's not clear what you want -- you want a ball bouncing and a hand clapping to be classified as a "hand clap"?  Or you want a ball bouncing to be "not a hand clap", or you want a ball bouncing to be a "ball bouncing", distinct from a "hand clap"?

Comment: Hand clapping or ball bouncing are just examples of which kind of sounds I want to analyse. It can be other sounds as well. The most important, when I am running my program I save the reference audio (or its representation) which is defined as hand clapping for example and I have to listen to MIC and detect the presence of the reference sound (hand clapping for this case). Hope it is clearer now ?

Comment: Hand clapping or ball bouncing are just examples of which kind of sounds I want to analyse but not both at the same time. It can be other sounds as well. The most important, when I am running my program: i) I save the reference audio (or its representation) which can be defined as hand clapping for example then, ii) I have to listen to MIC and detect the presence of the reference sound (hand clapping for this case). iii) Once I get a similar sound to hand lapping I notify the user. Hope it is clearer now ?

Comment: Yes, it is.  Now, this is Stackexchange, where they want the whole question in the question, and the answers in the answers.  Could you **edit your question** with the above clarification?

Comment: Sorry for the catechism, but I think you're asking for more than is possible: You want to take a reference file with a recording of a specific hand clapping in a specific room into a specific microphone under specific conditions (or a specific ball bouncing, or a specific dog barking etc.).

Then you want an application that identifies *any* hand clapping, or *any* ball bouncing, or *any* dog barking.  Yes?

Comment: It sounds like OP wants the user to be able to record a sound (or use a previous recording) and then run the program in a mode that detects the presence of that sound again. Is this correct, @newdevos?

Comment: Yes  @AnalogEE, your understandig is perfect. What do you mean by "OP" ? Are you aware about some application doing that or it is new thing ? Your recommandation of " matched filter" remains avilable ?

Comment: Original Poster, you. You would likely benefit from a numeric/matrix/linear-algebra library as well as functions that load audio data into vector form and take mic input as a vector. You want to make sure the sampling rates of both match or things get more complicated.

Answer (score -1):

What you're interested in sounds like a generic version of a [matched filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter). I'm not going to be able to speak to the software aspect of how you implement the file handling and "always-on" listening ability of this problem, but from a signal processing perspective, that's what you want to look into. It's worth noting that your filter is unlikely to match *any* hand clapping or *any* ball bouncing based on the reference waveform, but the magnitude of the matched filter response should give you a pretty reliable measure of how close the input is. You can use more advanced techniques if you get a lot of false alarms, like requiring the filter response to be a certain SNR by taking constant ambient noise measurements and comparing the amplitude to those.

EDIT: I re-read your question and am convinced this is the correct approach, but I suggest against trying to find a file-level solution to this issue. What you want to do is open the "reference" file and time-reverse the audio data. Then as mic input comes in, you convolve it with the reversed reference waveform (this is matched filtering). A strong response (impulse) from that convolution output indicates a match. In terms of tools you don't even need a powerful audio library, just something that can get the audio in 1-D vector form and then a time-reverse and 1-D convolution (common operations in matrix libraries).

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. I have to read more about this topic to understand it better in order to implement it.

Comment: Good way to learn this quick would be to experiment with basic code. Take the data from your audio file and time-reverse it to create the matched filter. Convolve the original data with that filter and you should see a large impulse in the output

Comment: Please I want to be sure that the meaning of "get the audio in 1-D vector" is equivalent to sampling the original audio and extract a raw audio data. In fact, in Android I did not find a clear code/API tha does this unless one API. This API ensures "the extraction of demuxed, typically encoded, media data from a data source". Then I will get the 1-D vector as suggested. Please tell me if the result matches with your recommandation of "get the audio in 1-D vector" ??
Thanks in advance.
Kid regards.

Comment: Sampling for me is related to this [explanation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sampling_(signal_processing))

Comment: Yes you want the raw samples in a vector where each element of the vector is one amplitude value separated in time by the sampling period. You will likely want to sum the channels if the audio is in stereo or any other multi-channel format. I am very surprised that no Android library exists to import a sound file into a numerical vector/array.

Comment: Thanks @AnalogEE for these precisions. I suggest to the interested Android developper to use AudioRecord class rather than MediaRecorder in order to access easily to the sample raw.

Comment: Please @AnalogEE, I want to be sure that the right convolution formula is x(n)∗h(n) =Σ x(k)h(n−k), in the sum (Σ) "k" is varying from -oo to ++oo. For my case, "x" is the 1-D time-reverse vector of the reference audio and "h" is the new listned audio to compare with. **This formula is the right one I should implement ?** In the reality the time value is not integer because for 1 second we get the amplitudes for these time values: 1/Sample_Rate, 2/Sample_Rate, ..., 1. **Shall I multiply by "Sample_Rate" value to get time in integer values ?**

Comment: h(n) is your filter, x(n) is your input signal, and you want to do it this way Σ x(n-k)h(k) for all values of k for which h(k) is not zero. n and k are time indices, so yes they are integers.

Comment: Thanks Keeg for your help and sorry for this delay (due to some constraints). The convolution method to compare the 2 audios was not very accurate in the sense that it generates a good score for non similar audios. No I am focusing on applying [FFT](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/99scientific/FFT.java.html) then compare the result of 2 audios. So I am looking for an efficient way to compare them. I need a clear for formula or algorithm to implement the proposed solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you make sure to time-reverse the reference signal? If you did and play a similar signal in you will get an impulse (spike) as a response.

Comment: In fact, when tried same sounds I get a value higher than 10^8. And when I check with non similar sounds I get also a value higher than 10^8. =>So it is very difficult to make the difference between a similar and non similar sounds. This is the implementation of convolution function.

Comment: `public static void convolve(double[] data,
                              double[] operator,
                              double[] output){
    //Apply the operator to the data, dealing
    // with the index reversal required by
    // convolution.
    int dataLen = data.length;
    int operatorLen = operator.length;
    for(int i = 0;i < dataLen-operatorLen;i++){
      output[i] = 0;
      for(int j = operatorLen-1;j >= 0;j--){
        output[i] += data[i+j]*operator[j];
      }//end inner loop
      //Divide by the length of the operator
    }//end outer loop
  }`

Comment: Thanks Keegs for your continous support. I am wondering if I can get some useful results if I perform the convolution on the 2 FFTs of th 2 audio file based on this [code](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/99scientific/FFT.java.html). If you agree with this suggestion, how cn I make use of the result (which is an array of Complex) in order to evaluate the similarity ? Thanks so much.

Comment: Convolving the FFTs is analogous to taking the FFT of the two signals multiplied together in time-domain. The inherent problem with using FFTs to do this is that completely unrelated sounding stuff can have nearly the same FFT. If I filter white noise through a bandpass filter from 440Hz to 880Hz for 10s, and I play a linear chirp from one of those notes to another in the same timeframe, their FFTs will be very similar, even though to our ears they sound nothing alike.

Comment: Thanks so much @Keegs. Once I get the convolution array as result, I shall compute the abs value of each value and then consider the maximum one of them as the simiarity value or how shall I proceed exactly ? Sorry I am lost that's why I am askig stupid questions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be continuously evaluating the mic input as it comes in and be computing the variance of the last x minutes of output from the filter. The variance of a complex random variable is just the variance of the real values plus the variance of the imaginary ones. This variance is a mean power measurement that you consider your noise level N by taking 10*log(variance). Then, for each filter output value you compute its power and consider a “detection” if its dB magnitude exceeds noise level by a particular threshold. That threshold is expressed as SNR and I suggest starting with about 10dB

Comment: Important note: power of any particular filter output signal will be 20*log(x) because you are dealing with a “voltage” whereas a variance is already a “power”. All log()s are base10 in my comments here.

Comment: I am trying to summarize what I understood from your recent comments. I remind that I am dealing with very short audios (about 2 seconds) in mono channel.
Currently, I have the recently listened signal (~2 seconds) stored where its samples are saved in 1-D vector (real values – not complex but I can set imaginary to 0 and have complex if mandatory/required) and another 1-D vector (real values) of time-reverse of the reference audio file.

Comment: The output/result of the convolution is also a 1-D vector. This is the variance [formula](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mathematics-mean-variance-and-standard-deviation) I am going to use. Then I compute 10xlog10(variance) and consider the sounds are similar if this value exceeds 10dB. Please @Keegs tell me whether I am wrong or my understanding is right?

Comment: Noise Level: 10*log10(variance(filter output of your typical non-matching sound));
Signal Level: 20*log10(abs(filter output));
SNR Threshold: 10dB (there are methods and equations for choosing this but let's put that off);
Detection: if and only if Signal Level >= Noise Level + SNR Threshold;

Comment: And yes, that variance equation is correct, just bear in mind you will need to separate the real and imaginary values into separate streams, take the variance of each stream, and then add them together to get the total variance.

Comment: Thanks so much Keegs for your reactivity and continuous help.
Regarding this statement “Signal Level: 20*log10(abs(filter output));” what is the right formula of abs(1-D vector) or you want to say variance?
Currently all my 1-D vectors (audio samples and convolution result) includes only real values. Shall I extend them by setting imaginary to 0 or it is not mandatory? So I keep handling real numbers?

Comment: you are taking the absolute value of every sample. the equation is sqrt(real_component^2 + imag_component^2). If your Imaginary component doesn't exist, just set it to 0.

Comment: Thank you. So, for an audio samples including an array/set of values, I should compute the mean of all abs values (1/n.∑(|x_i|)) or the sum of all these abs values (∑(|x_i|)) or search the max of all abs values or...? Sorry another time for these stupid questions

Comment: It’s more just if any sample in the file exceeds the derived threshold. You can calculate the noise level and threshold per-file if you don’t think the noise level will change much within a given file. Adjust the SNR threshold empirically until you get rid of most false alarms but still detect the sound.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My question is how shall I compute this abs(filter output) ? I have looking in some tools like matlab to see what is the result of log (an array) and the result is an array of each one of the different elements. So my question : shall I consider the output like an aray ? if it is the case how can compare an array to real values ?

Comment: By abs({e_i}), do you mean the Euclidean norm in IR^(n) as defined [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Vector_spaces) so its formula is abs({e_i}) = sqrt(∑(e_i)^2) ? My understanding is OK or not? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I’ve explained this already, you evaluate on a sample-by-sample basis against the threshold. 20log10(abs(sample)) and the absolute value is the root-square or just convert negative to positive (you indicated no complex values).

Answer (score -1):

A hand clap has a very high intensity and so I believe that you can detect the time location using an intensity threshold.
For comparison purposes you can do a direct comparison of FFT, using for example mean square error or other metric.

Comment: Hi Filipe, I am following your recommandation. In fact, I implemented and applied FFT on both audios (having same size) but I am wondering how to compare them. You were pointing Mean Square Error. So I want to get a clear formula that I can impelemnt in java. Now, the result of [FFT](https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/99scientific/FFT.java.html) is an array of Complex objects(having imaginary and real attributes). Would be possible please to explicit how to perform it for this kind of FFT result ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: From the FFT you just need the magnitudes, so you must calculate ABS value. To estimate the difference between spectrums you can calculate SQRT( SUM(  (x1-y1)^2 + (x2-y2)^2 + ... ) )

Comment: Thanks Filipe. Assuming I have 2 arrays of complex numbers, X and Y as result of FFT. First, I have to compute the [absolute value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value#Complex_numbers) of each complex number in the 2 arrays. Second I apply this formula: SQRT( SUM( (x1-y1)^2 + (x2-y2)^2 + ... ) ). Hope my understanding is right ?